# arguments to higher order function weirdness in scala

Tags: scala

I'm working on the assignments on Coursera's Scala course and have a question.  Out of curiosity, I've switched from an anonymous function to a defined one:

```
object sets {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    type Set = Int => Boolean
    def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = {println("in contains elem  ="+elem);s(elem)} 
    def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = {      //println("in singleton elem ="+elem); (x: Int) => x == elem}

      def singletonSetF(x: Int): Boolean = {
        println ("in singleton elem ="+elem+", x="+x)
        elem == x
      }
      singletonSetF
    }    
    println(contains(singletonSet(69), 6))
  }
}
```

And here is the output:

in contains elem  =6

in singleton elem =69, x=6

false

I believe the code is correct and working properly. My question is how and why does the "elem = 6" argument passed from the contains method, get assigned to "x = 6" in the singletonSetF method? Is the contains function call "s(elem)" a call to singletonSetF rather than singletonSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contains` function takes two arguments: a `Set` and an `Int`. We are trying to test whether the `Set` contains the `Int`.

The Set is actually a function of type `Int => Boolean`, as defined by the type alias for `Set`.

We create this first argument by calling `singletonSet`, which returns a function (`singletonSetF`). However, `singletonSetF` is a closure - it captures the value of `elem` passed into `singletonSet`, which in this case is 69.

Finally we call `s(elem)`. `s` is the closure containing the value 69. `elem` is the value 6, which is then bound to the parameter 'x' in `singletonSetF`.

**Important**: The code is a little confusing because you use `elem` to mean two different things in two different places - in `contains`, it is the value we are testing for membership of the Set; in `singletonSet`, it is the sole member of the Set. Renaming one of these may help a lot!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The two uses of elem were confusing, thanks to my slavish cutting and pasting of the original assignments. The wikipedia on closures is another good resource with some interesting and practical examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that you assume that a `Set` is kind of a fixed data structure once you obtain it from `singletonSet`. However, it is just a function that can be called. `s(elem)` calls it and ends up in executing the code in `singletonSetF`.

**Here is what happens:** `singletonSet(69)` calls the `singletonSet` function. This function returns a function value of the `singletonSetF` function. The function value acts as kind of a wrapper around a local function or method. You don't see the wrapper but its added implicitly because `singletonSetF` cannot be returned directly (it's a local function that cannot be passed around).

`contains` receives this function value which is properly typed as `Int => Boolean` and calls the function with the value `6`. The function value/wrapper then calls the real `singletonF` with value `6`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `singletonSetF` call, made in the `singletonSet` method when called with the value `69`, results in a `Set` instance, which in this case is an instance of a function from `Int` to `Boolean` (`Int => Boolean`). The function is created at this point (although it does "close" over the value `69` for `elem`), not evaluated, so `x` hasn't been set here.

Then, when `contains` is called, it runs the line `s(elem)` where `elem` here (not the same `elem` closed over by `singletonSetF`!) is the paramter value `6`.

The line `s(elem)` is a call to that earlier-created function (`s` here is the same `Set` - hence the same `Int => Boolean` instance - created by the call to `singletonSet`), passing the value of the parameter `elem` (passed in to `contains` as the value `6`) into that function.

At this point the function is executed, with `x` = `6`, producing the printed statements you observed.